# WebAPI not working in Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a POST WebApi that i can call as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var TheData = {
    Number: "7181112222",
    Username: "myusername",
    Password: "mypassword",
    enable: "True",
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: "False",
    url: "http://www.######.com/someapi/api/SettingsConfig",
    data: TheData
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
}).error(function (msg) {
    alert('Fail');
});

</script>
```

I will get an alert of 'Success' when i run this code.

When i run this code in fiddler...yipes!!

POST
http://www.######.com/someapi/api/SettingsConfig
Number=6464482035&Username=metheuser&Password=9999&enable=True

## 404 error

Why the inconsistancy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the javascript snippet you're posting a JSON object, while in the fiddler example it's an x-www-form-urlencoded string.

Have you tried including the `Content-Type` header with your request:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and posting the string
- `application/json` and posting the JSON object

What does your controller's method signature look like - do you hit the method in the second example at all or is it erroring out before that?

What does 404 actually mean in this context - 'number' not found / post data null ?

Answer (score 0):

There's two possible reasons of such behavior:

- Incorrect `Content-Type` which should be `application/json` value set;
- Not enabled [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your API (in this case you're not allowed to call API from untrusted domains);